# Can I preview/run my CSS and HTML code before I upload it to WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a coding novice who wants to create their own blog page.

I've been studying HTML and CSS using Codecademy. I blog through wordpress.org with Bluehost as the hosting platform.

1. what free programmes out there will allow me to run/preview my HTML and CSS code to see if it works?

   - or is there a plugin available for WordPress that I should install?
2. how do I then upload my HTML and CSS code to my wordpress.org blog (via Bluehost)

   - there is an upload button which allows me to select a .zip file but what should this contain? I'm assuming it should contain my HTML file and my CSS file

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your HTML in notepad if you want. But I reccomend using an editor. Good beggining programs are Sublime Text (https://www.sublimetext.com/3) and when you get comfortable, Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/). You should create a folder with all your files - index.html (it doesnt have to be index but must end in .html), main.css (css file), and javascript file. This is beggining front-end  To "run" the code simply right click and choose "open with google chrome" (or any other browser). I am not very familiar with WordPress but i suppose you can upload that project folder to it. I hope I helped...

Also watch a few html css and js tutorials...

edit: This is basic front-end and you are not running your website on a server only viewing what it will look like.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your first question: you can [download](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and use Visual Studio Code, it's free and you have the option to run your files in a live server as seen in the photo below.

[image]